# Create an ID for articles in a php_while(have_posts())

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a Wordpress template and, for the news part of the homepage, I have created a template to include the last 3 news of the wordpress.

I tried something with :nth-child() first, hoping it can work when my 3 articles are created, but it doesn' work.

Now, I think the best solution is to put an ID for each articles when the are created, but I don't know how as they are created by the php_while itself (i.e. I just have the template of it in index.php).

Here is the excerpt where I have the template and my php_while :

```html
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php static $count = 0; if ($count == "3") { break; } else { ?>
    <article>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </article>
  <?php $count++; } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can someone help me with an easy method in order to do it? (it will then help me for the CSS part of the website).

Comment: Could you update your question with some more information? What does `have_posts()` return? It seems that you want to fetch the last 3 posts from db and show that. You don't want to fetch them all and only show the 3 most recent ones.

Comment: Hi ! I want to find the 3 most recent articles on my wordpress database, then put them an ID for each one. I don't know what you mean by "What does have_posts() return?, as I found this solution on internet, I'm not a developer myself (not on php at least), sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You want to query the 3 most recent posts first, you could probably use this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/.

You want to add a query argument for 3 posts, since default is 10:

```php
$query = array(
  'numberposts' => 3
);

$posts = wp_get_recent_posts($query);
```

Then you need to loop over those posts to display them, you could use foreach for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. *Note that you don't need the & operator, since you're not manipulating the actual object.*

Every post has an $ID, so if you want to have some unique html id on article you can do that with `<article id="post-<?php echo $post->$ID ?>">`. This would result in id's like: `<article id="post-1">`

```php
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) >
  <article id="post-<?php echo $post->$ID ?>">
    <?php get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'medium'); ?>
      <h3><?php get_the_title($post); ?></h3>
      <?php get_the_excerpt($post); ?>
   </article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Disclaimer**: That's more or less the gist of it. Might not be syntactically completely correct.

Comment: Will the loop create an ID for each article ? I really need a solution after allmy articles are displayed thaht they also will get a class / ID in order to put some CSS for each

Comment: @Karl do you want a html id on the `<article>` tag? I'll update my answer to do so.

Comment: If possible, yes, I want an ID for each article because I'm working under a grid layout, so I need to have different IDs for the 3 articles displayed to place them with grid-row/column

Comment: I tried the solution with php foreach but it doesn't work (whole page is down when I put this instead of php while).  I tried to put the <article id="post-<?php echo $post->$ID ?>">  in what I already had, but it returns me "post-Array" in the 3 articles I display, not a different ID for each one, do you know how to change that? For the articles, it already displays me the 3 most recent articles with the solution I told before